Socket.io Response Malformed When Using Nginx as a Reverse Proxy
I am experiencing an issue with my Socket.io application when running in a production environment behind an Nginx reverse proxy. In my local environment, everything works perfectly. However, in production, the response from Socket.io seems to contain unexpected bytes and appears malformed.
Here is an example of the malformed response:
�   �0{"sid":"MhgRqiFEuwgqrG3CAADM","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}

My Nginx server block configuration for Socket.io is as follows:
location /socket {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    proxy_send_timeout 3600;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_no_cache $http_upgrade;
    gzip off;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

I am also using Cloudflare, but I don't think it's relevant because the problem also occurs when I try the same directly via the server's IP address.
Does anyone know why the response might be getting malformed like this, and how I can fix it?
I appreciate any help or insights you can provide!
I tried modifying the content-type, and few other headers and Nginx configurations, also tried a few socket.io versions.
